# Get information of Mysql database from android app using Retrofit, PHP, JSON and WAMP

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, retrofit2

PHP file stored in www directory of WAMP

```
<?php
//Response array JSON
$response = array();

//Connexion to the db local in WAMP
include("connexion_db.php");
$idcom = connexobject("database_app_android","myparam");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM products";

$result = $idcom->query($sql);

if(!$result)
{
    //Cannot read
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["mesage"] = "SQL query has timed out";
}
else
{
    if($result->num_rows > 0)
    {
        //Products founds
        $response["products"] = array();

        while($row = $result->fecth_object())
        {
            $product = array();
            foreach ($row as $key => $value)
            {
                $product[$key] = $value;
            }

            //Add product to the response JSON array
            array_push($response["products"], $product);
        }

        $response["success"] = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        //0 product found
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["mesage"] = "No products found";
    }
}

//Encode and send response in JSON format
echo(json_encode($response));

$response->free();
$result->free();
$idcom->close();
?>
```

Android API

```
public interface CatalogAPI {
    @GET("/products")
    Call<List<Product>> getProductList();

    @GET("/products/{product}")
    Call<Product> getProduct(@Path("product") int productId);
}
```

Android part using retrofit

```
//Retrofit
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("http://10.0.2.2:3000/MyAndroidApp/get_all_product.php")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build();
CatalogAPI service = retrofit.create(CatalogAPI.class);
service.getProductList().enqueue(new Callback<List<Product>>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<List<Product>> call, Response<List<Product>> response) {
        Log.i("retrofit","DOWNLOAD OK");
        for (Product p : response.body())
        {
            Log.i("retrofit","Product : " + p.getName());
            catalog.add(p);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<List<Product>> call, Throwable t) {

    }
});
```

Please, why this doesn't work ? I use the Android studio emulator. The php script encode to json all products founds in the mysql database. The MySQL database is on a local server wamp

Answer (score 0):

Please add logging interceptor to your retrofit client, this would help to find where is the problem .

Gradle Change

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.3.1'
```

Code Change

```
HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();  
// set your desired log level
logging.setLevel(Level.BODY);

OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();  
// add your other interceptors …

// add logging as last interceptor
httpClient.addInterceptor(logging);  // <-- this is the important line!

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()  
   .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
   .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
   .client(httpClient.build())
   .build();
```

Comment: I've no error. It was the port connection which was wrong. I have modified the php script that encode to JSON only an array with a product with a name. But I don't know why the response body is always null ...

Comment: Couldn't understand is problem still persist ? If yes this will help you to see the network response from server .

Answer (score 0):

In php file write

```
while($row = $result->**fetch**_object())
```

instead of

```
while($row = $result->**fecth**_object())
```

Answer (score 0):

Good day, i know this is coming late though, but the problem seems to come from the way PHP encodes into json array.
PHP adds extra features like "\n\r" and more to encode into json array, which is totally different from what Retrofit 2 is expecting. 
Retrofit 2 expects something like:

```
[ 
{ "name": "John Doe", "address": "60, station road", "mobile": "1" }, 
{ "name": "Doe Chujwu", "address": "6, Morgan Estate", "mobile": "2" }
 ].
```

Hence change your output to echo the above give format and then would your code work.
I hope it helps.
NB: also test that you can access your server homepage on the emulators browser. (This is to ensure that your are using the right ipaddress to connect).